# Unable to launch Eclipse

Tags: java, git, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, error-log

I installed Eclipse recently. When I try to launch Eclipse, it is showing the following popup.[Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iv9Jm.png). I deleted the metadata of workspace, but it didn't work. I also thought of changing the preference unchecking, but I was not able to start Eclipse itself. Please help.

Error Message is a follows:

```
!SESSION 2020-09-01 12:40:51.755 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.15.0.I20200305-0155
java.version=1.8.0_251
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_IN
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.cdt.docker.launcher 4 0 2020-09-01 12:40:54.258
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.cdt.docker.launcher [673]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.linuxtools.docker.core; bundle-version="[4.0.0,5.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.linuxtools.docker.core; bundle-version="4.7.0.202006092019"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.linuxtools.docker.core [763]
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.xml.bind; version="2.3.3"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.linuxtools.docker.ui; bundle-version="[4.0.0,5.0.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.linuxtools.docker.ui; bundle-version="4.7.0.202006092019"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.linuxtools.docker.ui [766]
         Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.xml.bind; version="2.3.3"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:1844)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1837)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1778)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1742)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1664)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.linuxtools.docker.core 4 0 2020-09-01 12:40:54.310
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.linuxtools.docker.core [763]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.xml.bind; version="2.3.3"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:1844)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1837)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1778)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1742)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1664)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.linuxtools.docker.ui 4 0 2020-09-01 12:40:54.357
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.linuxtools.docker.ui [766]
  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: javax.xml.bind; version="2.3.3"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:1844)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1837)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1778)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1742)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1664)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)
```

Comment: It seems something got corrupted in your installation. And as you have removed the metadata folder as well, it will be dificult to guess the issue. So Uninstall the eclipse..remove all the files associated with the installation..remove the temp files as well....Do a fresh install from the authentic Eclipse site..latest version...And Try again.

Comment: I have added a part of the error log in the question. Please check

Comment: That deleting the metadata folder helps is a hoax spread on Stack Overflow. Hopefully you have a backup so you can restore it. Please show the whole error log starting with `!SESSION`.

Comment: The log says that in your Eclipse installation a plugin (containing the `javax.xml.bind` package in version 2.3.3 or higher) is missing that is required by [Eclipse Docker Tooling](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-docker-tooling). This can happen when you delete files, as you did with the `.metadata` folder or something went wrong by installing/uninstalling/updating something in Eclipse. Does starting with a fresh workspace (`-data <path-to-empty-folder>`) work? If yes, does updating your Eclipse and installed plug-ins (_Help > Check for Updates_) help?

Comment: Starting with new workspace is not working. Again facing the same issue

Comment: Your Eclipse installation is broken. Therefore, it would be best if you would install the current Eclipse version from scratch. If you want to repair your existing installation instead, please answer the following questions: Did you delete files or install/uninstall/upgrade (if yes, in which way did you do this exactly) anything in Eclipse? Do you need Eclipse Docker Tooling?

Comment: I didn't delete anything except metadata. I installed  the following packages: 1."Web, XML, Java EE and OSGI Enterprise Development". 2."Programming langauges -> Eclipse Java Development Tools". After this I faced the isue.

Comment: Thank you @howlger for your time. I have re-installed the Eclipse as you have stated. Now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Your **Eclipse installation is broken**: according to the log a plugin (containing the `javax.xml.bind` package in version 2.3.3 or higher) is missing that is required by the [Eclipse Docker Tooling](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-docker-tooling). This might be an issue with an installed plugin maybe in combination with the outdated Eclipse you have.

In this case, the easiest solution is probably to **[install a current Eclipse from scratch](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/)** (maybe the *Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers* which can then be extended by additional plugins). It is also possible to uninstall or update existing plugins from the command line, but that would probably take longer and be more difficult since the real reason causing this issue is unknown.